# How to simulate 30Kbps Network link

Tags: ethernet

I am developing C#/.NET application and at production site we have some exotic 30Kbps Ethernet network link. I am testing my app on network card 100Mbps and all works, but is seems some queuing behaves differently on slow links.

How do I set my desktop Ethernet Network card to speed 30Kbps to simulate my production site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://netlimiter.com/ - you can use it to throttle bandwidth down to what you need.